# How do streaming apps like netflix and BBC Iplayer work?

Tags: android, audio

Firstly I just want to say hello to the Stack Over Flow community. This is my first post so please be gentle with me.

I work with a small radio production company. We make radio/audio content for a number of international broadcasters. We would like to create our own Android application to enable users to stream some of our archive and also fresh content. We would like the ability to be able to curate the content and change it over time.

I realise software like the BBCiplayer will be the intellectual property of BBC Future Technology so we would not look to replicate this directly as we are a much smaller organisation and do not have the same resources. I think it is unlikely the BBC would license the technology to us.

The idea of having a data-base of audio files (because it would be audio not video in our case) that can be streamed via an Android app (Android because we don't work with Mac as a company) seems in theory not to be so complicated but I really don't know.

The closest approximation to what we would want is a simpler version of the BBCiplayer Radio or the RTE radio player.

I would like to know in layman's terms what are the different elements one would need to go about creating this kind of thing? Comments about media, whether this is a good business model or whether small media companies can compete with global retailers like Amazon are interesting but not relevant to me at this stage.

I guess you need a server or servers to store the audio

Bandwidth and a I guess you would call it 'data' plan to manage how much data you use on the internet streaming to all your users. I guess the more users you have the more it costs.

a media player of some kind

some software to link the media player to the audio on the servers

art-work/graphics

something to measure usage, analytics so you could measure the popularity of a certain show for example.

what else?

On a scale of app development with 0 being easiest and 10 being hardest how difficult would it be? We have some research which tells us we might reach 50,000 downloads in the first year.

If people are going to say 'use Soundcloud' I would rather you didn't comment as perhaps you don't understand the look and feel of what we are trying to create. Also this is not 'pod-casts' it is quality, edited and fully-mixed, professional, sound rich audio of the type broadcast by Voice of America, CBC, NHK, ABC (Australia), BBC, Deutsche Welle.

I have used several forums before and I would appreciate if you are inclined to post something negative or sarcastic that you don't post.

My background is in media production. Since December 2015 I have been working on the Codecademy Python course (which is possibly not useful for building the kind of app I want to create). I am now 49% through the course. I have been doing it in grabbed moments and trying not to rely on the Q&A forum to just look up the answers but writing out pseudocode on scraps of papers and trying out things in IDLE. The only thing I have really built out of my own initiative so far is a choose your own adventure story which I know is probably a bit lame and it didn't even work that well..anyway going off topic...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Yes your question feels off-topic as it boils down to `I would like to know in layman's terms what are the different elements one would need to go about creating [an audio streamer app]?` Given the breath of information available via search engine I'm not sure its a good fit. Curiously there is a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13624048/what-is-the-best-way-to-stream-a-audio-file-to-website-users-listners which may answer some your questions or provide further direction for research.

Comment: Hi Morrison Chang. Thankyou for your comment.

Comment: Theoretically the information is 'out there' to do anything. I learn socially. Would it be sad if as a society we lose the ability to learn through human interactions? I've asked various questions before online and people quip 'google is your friend' but there is more to the process of learning (at least for my brain). This is a technical forum and you seem to be a long standing member so I will defer to you. I am going to a coding meet up in my city tonight. Your comment is appreciated.

Comment: Meetups are a great place to ask these questions and if you are in a large enough city may give you leads to domain experts. Good luck.

Comment: Hey! Actually I went to the local meet up. No experts turned up because there was grid-lock in my city that evening. However I did learn from my colleague that we already have a company that has created a 'back-end' that they will either let us use or license cheaply. All we need to do is create a 'front end' public app.

Comment: Feel free to delete this question and return to this site when you have a more appropriately directed question.